# trigger or computed field

Tags: sql, firebird

I wonder when I want to display result of calculating some fields in the same table should I do it as computed field or by using "before insert or update" trigger ?.

Note: I found similar question but it was for SQL Server and I need to know when I display the result in a grid with many records visible, if the computed field will affect performance in this case.

Example of the calculation I use now in a computed field:

```
field_1 * (
  iif(field_2 is null,0,1)
 +iif(field_3 is null,0,1)
 +iif(field_4 is null,0,1)
 +iif(field_5 is null,0,1))
```

Comment: Are you talking about DB schema and FB server performance? Is is not clear how this Q relates to [delphi].

Comment: What exactly does "calculating some fields" mean? Is it a simple calculation, like `quantity * unitprice` to display `total price`? Or is it something much more complicated? The question doesn't make sense, anyway; a `before insert or update` only runs *before insert or update*, not on a `select` that you would use to "display results". If you're actually storing the calculated results in a column in the table during `insert or update`, it's not "displaying results", but "inserting or updating data", which are not the same thing. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? You still haven't explained what you're asking here. There's no connection between "selecting a calculated column" and a "before insert or update trigger", so there's no way to compare a performance difference. They don't do the same thing, and can't be used to do the same thing. **What is your question?**

Comment: @KenWhite I was writing this comment and you replied faster !! ... I dont need to store the result in a field nor I wont need it to use in a where clause but I was just wondering if I used computed field to display the result in a Delphi grid with many rows does this will affect performance ? if so should I use trigger to store the result ? Another question: From testing I can use a trigger to do the same calculation so why I cant use it ?

Comment: @KenWhite if you have an answer post it please

Comment: Done. I'm also removing the `delphi` tag, as this question has nothing to do with Delphi. It's strictly a Firebird SQL question, and the `delphi` tag simply does not apply. I'm also adding the `sql` tag.

Comment: @KenWhite if you use a trigger to store a calculated value instead of a computed column you don't incur the cost of calculation on select but only on insert or updates to the row. The effect is similar to a persisted computed column in sql server

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I thought I'd covered that in my answer below.

Comment: @KenWhite not entirely, because it looks like (or can be read as) you don't understand what a `before update or insert` trigger would do (calculate the value and store it)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: ??? Where did you get that impression? I clearly discussed both, mentioned that triggers fire when data is inserted, updated, or deleted, and mentioned that triggers were fine if the data was fairly static and you intend on storing the data in the table. But thanks for the insult anyway.

Comment: @KenWhite First reading your comments above and then your answer just made it look that way to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigger only works if you're storing the information in the table, because they only get fired when an actual `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` happens. They have no effect on `SELECT` statements. Therefore, the actual question becomes "Should I calculate column values in my `SELECT` statement, or add a column to store them?".

There's no need to store a value that can be easily calculated in the `SELECT`, and there's seldom a performance impact when doing a simple calculation like the one you've included here.

Whether you should store it depends on many factors, such as how frequently the data changes, and how large the result set will be for your typical query. The more rows you return, the greater the impact of the calculations, and at some point the process of calculating becomes more costly than the increased storage requirements adding a column incurs. However, if you can limit the number of rows returned by your query, the cost of calculations can be so negligible that the overhead of maintaining an extra column of data for every row when it's not needed can be higher, as every row that is inserted or updated will have the trigger execute even when that data isn't being accessed.

However, if your typical query returns a very large number of rows or the calculation is extremely complex, the calculation may become so expensive that it's better to store the data in an actual column where it can be quickly and easily retrieved. If data is frequently inserted or updated, though, the execution of the trigger slows those operations, and if they happen much more frequently than the large `SELECT` queries then it may not be worth the tradeoff.

There's at least one disadvantage (which I failed to mention, but you asked in a comment below) to actually storing the calculation results in a column.If your calculation (formula) logic changes, you have to:

- Disable the trigger
- Update all of the rows with a new value based on the new calculation
- Edit the trigger to use the new calculation
- Re enable the trigger

With the calculation being done in your query itself, you simply change the query's SQL and you're done.

So my answer here is

- It's generally better to calculate the column values on the fly unless you have a clear reason not to do so, and
- "A clear reason to do so" means that you have an actual performance impact you can prove is related to the calculation, or you have a need to `SELECT` very large numbers of rows with a fairly intense calculation.

Comment: just one thought hit me: I use many different equations so if my boss tell me to change the equation then all stored values will be wrong and I would need to update the whole table that is not the case if I used a computed field ?

Comment: Right. If you have stored field values and the calculation changes, you need to disable your trigger, update all stored values, edit the trigger code, and then reenable the trigger. If you just calculate in your SQL, you simply change the SQL. I've added this information to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Performance should be fine, except with larger tables when your computed field becomes part of a WHERE clause. The other thing is, even if computed by other fields, if your requirements allow to overwrite the calculated value for some reason. Then you need a real physical field as well.

Comment: Since "doing some calculations to display results" isn't anything that would be done in a "before insert or update trigger", you're comparing apples and oranges and saying "performance should be fine". Performance of what? Doing a calculation, or using a trigger that will never run because you're not doing an "insert or update"? This answer makes no more sense than the question asked. You should probably delete it before you start losing rep.